# MDX : combining data from different tables

Tags: mdx, iccube

How can I combine data coming from different tables.

Let's assume I have 2 tables:

**First with sales:**

- id shop
- id product
- date
- amount

**Second with stocks:**
actually, with the same structure

- id shop
- id product
- date
- amount

I need to analyze for how many days' stock there is in the shop now. For that I need to calculate the average sale per shop per day for last 20 weeks and then divide the remaining stock by the average sales rate.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a actual problem in MDX as you can combine dimension over different fact tables.

You need to create your 3 dimension (using reference table or similar) :

id_shop -> [Shop]
id_product -> [Product]
date -> [Time]

Now we need to add the two tables as 'fact' tables. Recall that Fact Tables are the ones defining measures.

In icCube create a default Cube, e.g. [Cube], and for each table create a 'measure group' (just click the '+' ).

[image]

Bind your tables to the dimension, the 'magic'wand will do the work and create a measure for each table (e.g. [Stock] & [Sales] ).

Once the schema is defined and deployed you can use both measures without taking even noticing they are coming from different tables :

```
     [Measures].[Sales] / [Measures].[Stocks]
```

Comment: The problem is they should be from different periods. For example i want to take today stock and divide it to average daily sales for past 12 weeks.

Comment: Olek, can you create another one with how to calculate the rolling average daily sales for the last 12 week ?